# Exercise on multivariable calculus: am I reasoning right?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Consider
$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} x^2+y^2 & x^2+y^2 \geq 1 \\\\ \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} & 0 < x^2+y^2 < 1\end{cases}
$$

Now, the domain of $f$ is: $D: \mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0, 0)\}$

When it's asked to check for the continuity of the function in all the points of its domain, I guess that it's really asked to only check for what happens when $x^2+y^2 = 1$.

- Question: could I turn this into a one dimensional problem where $x^2+y^2 = m$ and hence studying the continuity of $f(m)$ which turns to be trivial? At least using directional limits or sequences...

I don't have any idea on how it would be to prove continuity in this case, as if I had to use the same method of $2$ variables function in the usual way (that is, with majorisation and distance). Is it doable?

Comment: Use polar coordinates. Let $g(r,\theta)=f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta).$ Check that $\lim_{r\to r_0,\theta\to\theta_0}g(r,\theta)=g(r_0,\theta_0)$ (in particular for $r_0=1$).

Comment: @AnneBauval We cannot use polar coordinates, because our professor decided to not teach them to us: he wants we reason without them (he says it's too easy otherwise)

Comment: If $g : D \to \mathbb R$ is given by $g(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ and if $h : (0,\infty)$ is given by $h(u) = \frac 1u,u<1$ and $h(u) = u, u \geq 1$ then $f$ equals $g$ composed by $h$. "Compositions of continuous functions are continuous" applies, and what makes this problem one-dimensional is that you only have to "argue" that $h$ is continuous because $g$ is a polynomial so continuity comes for free. Of course I don't know what's been covered in your course (although I answered your last question, remember me?)

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Seen like this was really straighforward!! Thank you so much again, limpid!

Comment: @Numb3rs But of course, great to be of service again. If you complete the problem, consider posting a complete answer. I need to leave so cannot write one.

Comment: Yes, to your question. You can consider $F(f(x,y)) = (F\circ f )(x,y)$ and study separately continuity of $f$ and $F$.

Comment: @Numb3rs I just posted a very simple-minded soluion to your problem.

Comment: Start by proving continuity at $(1,0)$ to get an idea of the $\epsilon-\delta$ argument. This is enough since it follows that $f$ is continuous at any other point on the circle, by composing with a rotation. Or, just do it in general (don't look at P. Lawrence's correct answer unless you really get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Being continuous means being continuous at every point $(x_0,y_0).$As you say, the main problem occurs when $(x_0,y_0)$ is on the unit circle, so I'll just do that case and leave the details of the other cases to you. Given $\epsilon>0$, we have to find $\delta>0$ such that $\vert f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0) \vert<\epsilon$ whenever $\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}<\delta$. Note that $f(x_0,y_0)=1$. First we observe that if $$\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}<\frac{1}{10}$$ then $\vert x-x_0 \vert<\frac{1}{10}$ and$\vert y-y_0 \vert<\frac{1}{10}$ , so, since $-1\le x_0,y_0 \le 1$, it follows that $\vert x\vert,\vert y  \vert <\frac{11}{10}$, so $$\vert  x+x_0\vert,\vert y+y_0\vert \le \frac{11}{10}+1=\frac{21}{10}$$ and thus $\vert x^2-x_0^2 \vert=\vert  x-x_0 \vert \vert x+x_0 \vert <\frac{21}{100}$Similarly, $\vert y-y_0^2 \vert< \frac{21}{100}$; hence $$\vert x^2+y^2-x_0^2-y_0^2 \vert<\frac{21}{50}$$ and $$x^2+y^2> 1-\frac{21}{50}=\frac{29}{50}$$. Thus $$\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}<\frac{50}{29}$$. Let $$\delta=\min(\frac{\epsilon }{10},\frac{1}{10}).$$ First, we see that,for $\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}<\delta,\vert x-x_0 \vert<\frac{\epsilon}{10},\vert x+x_0  \vert<\frac{21}{10}$ and similarly for $y$ so $$\vert x^2-x_0^2+y^2-y_0^2 \vert\le \vert x-x_0 \vert\vert x+x_0 \vert+\vert y-y_0  \vert\vert 
y+y_0 \vert<\frac{\epsilon}{10}\frac{21}{10}+\frac{\epsilon}{10}\frac{21}{10}=\frac{21\epsilon}{50}<\epsilon$$To show continuity at $(x_0,y_0)$, we see that for $\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0^2}<\delta,$ $$\vert f(x,y)- f(x_0,y_0)\vert$$ $$=\vert 
  x^2+y^2-x_0^2-y_0^2\vert<\epsilon \text{ if }x^2+y^2 \ge 1$$ or $$=\vert \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}-1\vert=\frac{\vert x^2+y^2-x_0^2-y_0^2  \vert}{x^2+y^2}$$ $$<\frac{21\epsilon}{50}\frac{50}{29}<\epsilon \text{ if } x^2+y^2<1.$$